# EF Core Connection Timeout ? but no exceptions

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.0

I have the following code in a healthcheck controller to confirm the EF Core database connection is working:

```
      using (var con = _dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection())
      {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Connecting to {con.ConnectionString}");
        try
        {
          await con.OpenAsync();
          con.Close();

          return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
          _logger.LogError(ex, "Connection failed"); 
        }
        finally
        {
          _logger.LogInformation("Connection test done");
        }

      }
```

When executed I see in the log an entry "Connecting to ..." with the correct connection string.
It never completes and I see no exception in the log either. The api ends with a 504 timeout.  My connection string has "...;Connection Timeout=10" but it seems to be taking a lot longer than that.

Im completely stumped.  Ive spend 4 hours with AWS support and they think it's my code.  We proved the network connection works so I guess they are correct but I dont know what else to do.  Ive turned on verbose logging also can there is nothing obviously from EF Core or SQL client.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Nope.  Nothing.  It takes about a minute to timeout.

Comment: Then I think you didn't wait long enough. The API timeout is different from the SQL connection timeout. Why don't you retry it and wait for 30 minutes or so (even though the API has already timed out)... you should see `Connection test done` eventually...

Comment: I have a 10 minute timeout for the requests but the browser still gives me a 504 in much less time than that.  Maybe the ALB is cutting is short?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that in the past the combination of a using statement and EF GetDbConnection() had some [issues](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7810).

Try doing it without the `using` block.

```cs
        var con  = _dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
        _logger.LogInformation($"Connecting to {con.ConnectionString}");

        try
        {
          await con.OpenAsync();
          con.Close();
          return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
          _logger.LogError(ex, "Connection failed"); 
        }
        finally
        {
          _logger.LogInformation("Connection test done");
        }
```

Comment: That seemed like a reasonable explanation... but sorry, I still get nothing.  No exception or finally logged.

Comment: I remove the async and now I see the error:  Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.